# Gettting problem when I tried to use camera in android

Tags: java, android, xml, file

Java code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn_camera:
                    if (i==21) {
                        Toast.makeText(FileUploadActivity.this,R.string.max_file_upload,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        ++i;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FileUploadActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
                            } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FileUploadActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS);
                            } else {
                                openCamera();
                            }
                        } else {
                            openCamera();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
    
     public void openCamera()  {
    
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createTempFile("Images", "IMG_", ".jpg"); //error
                Log.i(TAG, "openCamera: Camera access"+photoFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(FileUploadActivity.this,"Unable to open",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           // takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
           // startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE);
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                File file = new File(Uri.fromFile(photoFile).getPath());
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            }
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
    
        }
        private File createTempFile(String storage,String fileName,String fileType) throws IOException {
            File imageFile = null;
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    File.separator + "CTrack" + File.separator + storage);
            boolean success = true;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success) {
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
                String imageFileName = fileName + timeStamp + "_";
                imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, fileType, folder);
            }
            return imageFile;
        }
        private String encodeImage(String path) {
            File imagefile = new File(path);
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            String encodeResponse="";
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
    
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                encodeResponse=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                encodeResponse="nofile";
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                encodeResponse="memory";
            }
            return encodeResponse;
    
        }

Permissions:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

error:
2021-05-03 12:52:30.921 9669-9669/com.transasia.ctrack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.transasia.ctrack, PID: 9669
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/CTrack/Images/IMG_2021-05-03T12%3A52%3A30_6074100336714487332.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:2083)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2388)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:977)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10759)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10744)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1703)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
```

App is working in android 9 and below 9 but when it comes to android 10 and 11, app is crashing and getting file error. I thought problem with creating temp file because there it gives me an error.
Thank you,........................................................................Thanks...........................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. In Manifest file - add provider inside

   `<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">`

   ```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
   ```
2. create provider_path.xml (res -> xml -> provider_path.xml)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <external-path
     name="external_files"
     path="." />
   </paths>
   ```
3. Add Camera permission

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
   ```

Comment: content.FileProvider (this part showing in red color) how to solve

Comment: Using AndroidX ?

Comment: Yes I'm using androidx

Comment: Import provider through androidx - android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"

Comment: I did still I'm not getting output

Comment: Now what is the issue?

Comment: I'm confused with this one because I solved it by using your code still camera option is not opening

Comment: For android 10 and 11 how to request runtime permission? is that same as before or anything new?

Comment: Did you add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in Manifest?

Comment: Yes I did but now all intent which I used in code with runtime permission is not working for example call, map etc.